# Magento 2.3.1 update issue

Tags: upgrade, magento2.3.1

We have recently updated magento from 2.2.3 to 2.3.1 using composer (with automated script), it went though fine but we get following error on indexing:

> Catalog Search indexer process unknown error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column
>   not found: 1054 Unknown column 'e.category_ids' in 'field list', query
>   was: SELECT `e`.`entity_id`, `e`.`type_id`, `e`.`category_ids`,
>   `e`.`sku` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`  INNER JOIN
>   `catalog_product_website` AS `website` ON website.product_id =
>   e.entity_id AND website.website_id = 1  INNER JOIN
>   `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `visibility_default` ON
>   visibility_default.entity_id= e.entity_id AND
>   visibility_default.attribute_id = '99' AND visibility_default.store_id
>   = 0  LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `visibility_store` ON visibility_store.entity_id= e.entity_id AND
>   visibility_store.attribute_id = '99' AND visibility_store.store_id =
>   '1'  INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `status_default` ON
>   status_default.entity_id= e.entity_id AND status_default.attribute_id
>   = '97' AND status_default.store_id = 0  LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `status_store` ON
>   status_store.entity_id= e.entity_id AND status_store.attribute_id =
>   '97' AND status_store.store_id = '1' WHERE
>   (IF(visibility_store.value_id > 0, visibility_store.value,
>   visibility_default.value) IN (3, 2, 4)) AND (IF(status_store.value_id
>
> > 0, status_store.value, status_default.value) IN (1)) AND (e.entity_id > 0) AND (e.entity_id < 501) ORDER BY `e`.`entity_id` ASC
> >     LIMIT 500

we are using ElasticSearch.

any suggestions? please.

Thanks

Comment: Looks like something has not updated properly.  Category_ids is not present in that table in my version of 2.3.1.  Maybe set error reporting to full in PHP.  You can do this by adding 
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); into you index.php file and app/bootstrap.php

Comment: I tired to run indexing from command line and it gave the above exception log even after adding error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); nothing in system.log, exception.log or error.log

Comment: Normally gives you the file that is the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it by running setup:upgrade again.